# html email does not send in codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter, email, smtp

This is my code to send HTML email but its not working properly. Just raw html code is shown in the email.

```
        $emailID = $this->input->post('email');
        $name = $this->input->post('name');

        $this->load->library('email');

        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
        $config['validate'] = FALSE;

        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from($emailID,$name);
        $this->email->to('vishvajitmahida009@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject('Email Testing');
        $this->email->message('from clientside mail'); 
        $this->email->send();  

        $message = $this->load->view('emailfile/file','',TRUE);             
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->from($emailID,$name);
        $this->email->to($emailID,$name);
        $this->email->subject('Email Testing');
        $this->email->message($message);   
        $this->email->send();
        //echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Comment: What is error message? Can you please add that?

Comment: If your email on the CI client used Gmail, don't forget to allow it in the setting. Or if you trying using your own @website.com, try using Gmail now to made sure that your code actually work. Sometimes your web host email server is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$this->email->initialize($config);`:

```
$this->load->library('email');  
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['validate'] = FALSE;
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

Comment: Thank u so much buddy.